# Position of scroll next to inline list with index

Tags: lists, filter, scrolling, scrollbars

Working on a custom filter of an ecommerce website, which has an inline frame since the list is really long. there will be an index so the used can jump to certain letters in the list. there will be a scroll bar too since this is an inline frame.

[image]

my question is whats the best way for the the inline scroll and index be positioned.

1. index on left, scroll on right
2. scroll on left, index on right
3. both overlapping
4. any other suggestions?

Comment: Hey, couple of questions before I answer. Is the site responsive? How much content is expected on the rest of the screen e.g. will it go below the fold of the screen?

Comment: no, the site isn't responsive. and yes it'll go below the fold as its on the side of a catalog page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar and alphabet-index next to each other is likely to be too fiddly for mobile users. Mobile users (at least on iOS) are used to using the index in a fast-scroll way. The iOS contacts app only has an index (on the right), no scrollbar.
Unless it is pure B2B or internal ECommerce for really old-school/ corporate audience, you should really take mobile into account.

If your search is "live", i.e. the list contains only filtered results, I could imagine that your scrollbar may disappear if the filtered list is small enough to fit. And that would leave you index in a strange floating place.

So I would advise:
Index on the left (even though this is different from 'standard' iOS),
scrollbar on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I would say definitely not overlapping. It would be very difficult for the users to select whatever they are looking for. It's the standard in every computer browser to have a scroll bar on the most right, so you should keep it this way.

What you should consider more is the spacing between the list lines, the index and scroll bar. I think it looks nice the way it is now, it doesn't look too crowded even though it includes the search bar, scroll bar and index all on the same screen. However, this is my opinion off just seeing gray lines instead of text. Once you have text, be sure to make the space between the list text and the scroll&index wide enough to not appear to messy.

Also, one thing that you need to keep in mind is how many of your users will visit the site via a device with a touchscreen. If the scroll bar and the index are too close to each other, they may be inadvertently clicking the index letters while wanting to pull the scroll bar and the other way around. Since you've said that the list is really long, you can assume that the index will be more popular (as long as the users know which word they are looking for). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Index on left and scroll on right is might be a good option. If the user uses the website from a mobile device then they cant able to select the alphabets as the screen size is too small and you cant accommodate all the alphabets in one single screen. so you can use like in the below image. The list is categorized by alphabetical order and each alphabet is separated by a separator. when the user scrolls down the scroll will also represents the current position of the alphabet. This helps the user to scroll fast to arrive at an exact alphabet filter the want to. This kind of approach is used by google to categorize the contact list in android devices.
[image: Scroll-list]